# How to write code behind for hyperlink button inside in obout grid?

Tags: asp.net

i just want to know, how to write Code behind(Hyperlink1_Click()), for the hyper link 
button inside in grid view.
Click--%>

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="l1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Mine.aspx" 
                CssClass="s11">Click Me</asp:LinkButton>


$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#GridBusOne a[id*='l1']").fancybox( {
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'hideOnOverlayClick':false,
        'hideOnContentClick': false,
        'closeClick' : false,
    });
 });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `LinkButton` instead as follows:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" OnRowCommand="grdProducts_RowCommand" ID="grdProducts" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                    CommandName="myLink" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' Text="Button"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And the code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var r = new Repository();
        this.grdProducts.DataSource = r.GetProducts();
        this.grdProducts.DataBind();
    }

    protected void grdProducts_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "myLink":
                this.lblMessage.Text = e.CommandName + " " + e.CommandArgument + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Which generates something like:

[image]

Comment: that is ok. But in my if i click the link button in obout grid, first time it shows the fancy box. If we click again it shows the page in Tab instead of fancy box.

Comment: You need to add more context, I am not following you, post your code

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#GridBusOne a[id*='l1']").fancybox( {
 'type' : 'iframe',
 'hideOnOverlayClick':false,<a href="Mine.aspx"  class="s11" id="s1">Click</a>--%>


    <asp:LinkButton ID="l1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Mine.aspx" CssClass="s11">Click Me</asp:LinkButton>

'hideOnContentClick': false,
'closeClick' : false,
        });
     });

Answer (score 0):

Use `GridView` Control's `ItemCommand` event
for more info [Go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx)

Comment: I am working with obout grid , normal is ok.Please my comments on jupol.